# Permanent TCP connection or connection etablishment at request processing

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am developing a TCP server, which shall communicate with the client, if specified tasks are finished. So I open on the server a socket and the client connects on it.
That connection can be used for data tranfers back to the client, too. That is quite okay.
But what about connection aborts and anything like that?

My thought was to connect each time to the server, when the client have to communicate with it. But how can I send data back to the client?
Shall I open a socket on the client side, too?

EDIT:
I have considered WCF, too. I think it could be a very good way to implements server client hierarchy.
What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the rest of your requirements. If we're talking a message that is in no rush that might be sent once a day, the right solution might be for the client to connect to the server periodically and check if there are any messages. If we're talking something that's more common and more in a rush, the right solution might be for the client to keep a connection open to the server at all times. In some cases, the right solution might be for the server to make a 'backwards' connection to the client, if possible -- perhaps with an option to fall back to a persistent connection from the client to the server if the 'backwards' connection isn't possible.

See this article on [Push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology), particularly the section on [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling).

Comment: There will be a lot of communication all the time, because there are events for the clients.

Comment: I have thought about WCF. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

From a runtime POV having the server connect to the client needs a network environment supporting this (firewall/IDS etc.).

IF you can't be sure that this is always the case then this option is ruled out IMO.

As for the client keeping the connection open:

I think this is a good option... you need to make sure that the client implementation detects any connection problems and automatically reconnects...

Whatever solution you implement you might need to implement a queue of events per client... depending on your requeirements these queues might even need to be persistent...

WCF can work in all the ways I described and offers several things (like serialization, optional session management, transport security etc.) which help build a robust and well-maintainable system... although a pure TCP/IP-based solution might be better performance-wise...